# Magento2 wordpress blog editor not working

Tags: magento2

I am using **Magefan Blog**, the post editor worked only when JS minify and merge is disabled. When I enable it again, it stops working.

*See attached image:* [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is one of the magento's bugs, it has nothing to do with **Magefan_Blog** extension. For more information, visit this-https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/11577

Comment: Yes, I have short out it already the "Klarna module" is culprit, i have disable it, Your answer may be help some one,  therefore i am going to accept it

Comment: Happy coding! :)